# SSL Certificate Trust Required for Services

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, sql-server, ssl

This is in a development system which is why i have a self generated SSL certificate. Its setup on our dev exchange server; i need to add a trust to call it from a CLR running inside SQL Server. Have downloaded teh certificate from IE but cant work out which certificate store to save it in; can anyone let me know.

The windows is windows 2003, doubt it matters but its exchange 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the certificate in the Trusted Root store for the security context (user) that will be executing the CLR code that makes the connection. This would be the SQL Server service account unless you are using impersonation.

For more info on CLR impersonation, check out this post from the SQL CLR Integration Team at Microsoft:
http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlclr/archive/2006/06/16/635003.aspx